# IOS how to detect the orientation completed

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, orientation

I have a renderer which based on the UIView. I can see the animation change when doing a rotation of the device leading the layoutSubviews call several times. Is there a way to detect the animation of the view when rotate the device is finished.

This is the layoutSubview call

```
public override void LayoutSubviews()
{
        base.LayoutSubviews();

        var size = base.Frame;
        Element.OnSizeChanged((int) size.Width, (int) size.Height);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the end of a `UIViewController` rotation via a coordinator completion handler within the `ViewWillTransitionToSize` method:

```
public override void ViewWillTransitionToSize(CGSize toSize, IUIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator coordinator)
{
    coordinator.AnimateAlongsideTransition(
        (IUIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext obj) => { },
        (IUIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext obj) => 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Transition Completion");
    });
    base.ViewWillTransitionToSize(toSize, coordinator);
}
```

Comment: I am overriding a UIView not UIViewController

Comment: @Simon An orientation change is handled by the `UIViewController` and its subviews are told to resize, they, themselves, to not know why. You could use the completion handler to call a method on the `UIView`, or a cleaner de-coupled way would be to post an event in the handler and have your subclassed `UIView`s subscribe to the event, you could also use `NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter`

Comment: Thank I will look at that.

Comment: How to do the completion handler?

Answer (score 0):

take a look on `viewWillTransitionToSize`.

> UIKit calls this method before changing the size of a presented view controller’s view. You can override this method in your own objects and use it to perform additional tasks related to the size change. For example, a container view controller might use this method to override the traits of its embedded child view controllers. Use the provided coordinator object to animate any changes you make.

[refer apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontentcontainer/1621466-viewwilltransition) for more details!!